# Error installing phpDocumentor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu

I'm trying to install phpDocumentor via PEAR as per the instruction on the [phpDocumentor2 GitHub repo](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2#pear-recommended). I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) with the Lubuntu desktop.

Step 2 `sudo pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor` is giving me the following error:

```
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/phpDocumentor-2.8.2.tgz"
Download of "phpdoc/phpDocumentor" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpdoc/phpDocumentor"
Download failed
install failed
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is bug related to unzipping downloadable contents with pear. To solve this issue, use `--nocompress` option after `install`.

Try this:

`sudo pear install --nocompress phpdoc/phpDocumentor`

another site advise to simply extract pear downloaded file and run `upgrade` with extracted result. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/773622/how-to-upgrade-pear-to-send-email-with-smtp-send-function-in-php) for further details.

**note:**

this will download phpDocumentor uncompressed source (approx. 67 MBytes)

***sources:***

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67075